# Classify values in a list based on original DF (Python 3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Fictional df called KW looks like this:

```
 Group    Subgroup    Word
 orange    zebra      keys
 green     lion       mouse
 blue      horse      captain
```

**Code I currently have** takes each of the words found under the "Word" column and replaces certain letters with other letters from a dictionary one at a time.  After this, creates a list of all these misspellings. So using the KW df:

```
kw = df[['Word',"Group","Subgroup"]]

words = kw.to_dict()["Word"].values()

md = {"m":"w","o":"z"}
md = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in md.items()}

newwords = []

for word in words:
    newwords.append(word)
    for c in md:
        occ = word.count(c)
        pos = 0
        for _ in range(occ):
            pos = word.find(c, pos)
            for r in md[c]:
                tmp = word[:pos] + r + word[pos+1:]
                newwords.append(tmp)
            pos += 1
```

returns

```
Word
keys
mouse
wouse
mzuse
captain
```

**What I am trying to do** is basically reclassify these misspellings into their appropriate Group/Subgroup based on the manipulated original word.  So ideally instead of spitting out a stand alone list of misspellings, it would look like this:

```
Group    Subgroup    Word
orange   zebra       keys
green    lion        mouse
green    lion        wouse
green    lion        mzuse
blue     horse       captain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow we need to associate the new word with the original word.
You could do that by storing in `newwords` 2-tuples such as `('mouse', 'wouse')`.
Then you could convert `newwords` into a DataFrame, and use `pd.merge` to merge `newwords` with `kw` by joining on the original word:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
kw = df[['Word',"Group","Subgroup"]]

words = df['Word']

md = {"m":"w","o":"z"}
md = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in md.items()}

newwords = []
for word in words:
    # Save both the original word and the new word
    newwords.append((word, word))
    for c in md:
        occ = word.count(c)
        pos = 0
        for _ in range(occ):
            pos = word.find(c, pos)
            for r in md[c]:
                tmp = word[:pos] + r + word[pos+1:]
                newwords.append((word, tmp))

newwords = pd.DataFrame(newwords, columns=['Word', 'New'])
# Merge on the original Word
result = pd.merge(newwords, kw, left_on='Word', right_on='Word', how='left')
result = result[['Group', 'Subgroup', 'New']]
result.columns =  ['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Word']
print(result)
```

yields

```
    Group Subgroup     Word
0  orange    zebra     keys
1   green     lion    mouse
2   green     lion    wouse
3   green     lion    mzuse
4    blue    horse  captain
```